# returning multiple attribute values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have a web page that allows the user to scroll through answering questions. To show their answer they simply click an li that changes the class onclick via jquery to show that answer has been selected. On some of these questions I only allow a single answer to be chosen (a single li to be clicked) and on others I allow multiple to be clicked. Once the questions are complete the user clicks submit and jquery takes the value of the data-url attributes with the "answerPick" class and appends to the website url for navigating to.

My issue is that the method I use to select the attributes of the "answerPick" class only returns the first value (an issue when ppl choose multiple values).

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#section-a .answer, #section-b .answer').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).siblings().hasClass("answerPick") == false) {
      $(this).toggleClass('answer answerPick');
    }

  });

  $('#section-c .answer, #section-d .answer').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('answer answerPick');
  });


  $('#submittah').click(function() {
    var q1 = $('#section-a').find('.answerPick').attr('data-url');
    var q2 = $('#section-b  .answerPick').attr('data-url');
    var q3 = $('#section-c  .answerPick').attr('data-url');
    var q4 = $('#section-d  .answerPick').attr('data-url');
    var finalURL = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4;
    window.location.href = finalURL;
  });


});
```

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gchis66/xorpyj82/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't redirect the page, but will console log out the final query (open developer tools and look at console) or change `console.log` to `alert()` if you're so inclined.. Are you wanting to pass the values along with keys to the next page (I've updated the finalURL to contain keys for the value pairs). To answer your question about more than 1 answer, you want to loop through the multiple selected classes, and push them to an array and then join them as a comma delimited list. You may need to encode your URL though when sending over the answers to the location, depending how you are retrieving the key/value parameters from the URL.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#section-a .answer, #section-b .answer').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).siblings().hasClass("answerPick") == false) {
      $(this).toggleClass('answer answerPick');
    }

  });

  $('#section-c .answer, #section-d .answer').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('answer answerPick');
  });


  $('#submittah').click(function() {

    var q1 = $('#section-a').find('.answerPick').attr('data-url');
    var q2 = $('#section-b  .answerPick').attr('data-url');
    var q3Multi = [];
    var q3 = $('.answerPick', '#section-c').each(function() {
      q3Multi.push($(this).attr('data-url'));
    });
    var q4Multi = [];
    var q4 = $('#section-d  .answerPick').each(function() {
      q4Multi.push($(this).attr('data-url'));
    });
    var finalURL = '?q1=' + q1 + '&q2=' + q2 + '&q3=' + q3Multi.join(',') + '&q4=' + q4Multi.join(',');
    console.log(finalURL);
    // window.location.href = finalURL;
  });


});
```

```css
/*  Core Styles */

body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  padding: 1em 0 !important;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #92c03c;
  border: 1px solid #494949;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5em 0;
}


/* Header Styles */

#showcase {
  min-height: 450px;
}

#showcase h1 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}


/* Section Styles */

#main section {
  display: block;
  min-height: 450px;
}

#submission {
  margin-top: 30px;
}


/* List Item Styles */

#main li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 4px #fff;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  -moz-border-radius: 80px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

#main li>span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 40%;
}

.answer {
  background: #1bb8d1;
}

.answerPick {
  background: #92c03c;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media(min-width:700px) {
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: xx-large;
  }
  #showcase p {
    font-size: medium;
  }
  #main h2 {
    font-size: xx-large;
  }
  #main li {
    font-size: large;
  }
  .btn {
    padding: 2em 4em;
    font-size: medium;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Header -->
<header id="showcase" class="grid">
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <p> Example txt</p>
  <a href="#section-a" class="btn">Get Started</a>
</header>
<!--Main Area -->
<main id="main">
  <!--Section A -->
  <section id="section-a">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <h2 class="content-title">Is this gift for a woman or man?</h2>
      <ul class="answer-options">
        <li class="answer" data-url="man"><span>Man</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="woman"><span>Woman</span></li>
      </ul>
  </section>

  <!--Section B-->
  <section id="section-b" class="grid">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <h2 class="content-title">What is the goal of the gift?</h2>
      <ul class="answer-options">
        <li class="answer" data-url="relaxation"><span>Relaxation</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="skincare"><span>Skincare</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="date-night"><span>Date Night</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="at-home-spa"><span>At home spa</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="beard-care"><span>Beard Care</span></li>
      </ul>
  </section>

  <!--Section C-->
  <section id="section-c" class="grid">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <h2 class="content-title">Price Point</h2>
      <ul class="answer-options">
        <li class="answer" data-url="0-5"><span>$5 or lower</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="5-10"><span>$5-$10</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="10-20"><span>$10-$20</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="20-50"><span>$20-$50</span></li>
      </ul>
  </section>

  <!--Section D-->
  <section id="section-d" class="grid">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <h2 class="content-title">Any other preferences?</h2>
      <ul class="answer-options">
        <li class="answer" data-url="cruelty-free"><span>Cruelty Free</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="vegan"><span>Vegan</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="gluten-free"><span>Gluten Free</span></li>
        <li class="answer" data-url="fragrance-free"><span>Fragrance Free</span></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="submission">
        <button id="submittah" class="btn">Submit</button>
      </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks! A simple solution that works very well. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery each function:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

This will loop all the elements.